# Excel Macros to populate data from master sheet into multiple template sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet that has a sheet with the structure as below:

[image]

I want to create separate sheet for each 'Model name'. My code below does it correctly.

```
    Option Explicit
Sub Splitdatatosheets()
'
' Splitdatatosheets Macro
'
'
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim vrb As Boolean
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4")
Set rng1 = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A4:BD4")
vrb = False
Do While rng <> ""
    For Each sht In Worksheets
           If sht.Name = Left(rng.Value, 31) Then
                sht.Select
                Range("A2").Select
           Do While Selection <> ""
                 ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
           Loop 
            rng1.Copy ActiveCell 
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate 
            Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0) 
            Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0) 
            vrb = True 
        End If
    Next sht 
    If vrb = False Then
    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = Left(rng.Value, 31)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3:BD3").Copy ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    Range("A2").Select               
    Do While Selection <> ""               
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate                    
    Loop
    rng1.Copy ActiveCell
    Set rng1 = rng1.Offset(1, 0)    
    Set rng = rng.Offset(1, 0)    
    End If    
vrb = False
Loop
End Sub
```

However, I want to create the sheets with a specific template. I want to populate the data in a template fashion. I want to populate the data in the below fashion:

[image]

I want to populate data in a template fashion. Any clue on how my code can be fixed?

Comment: Can you show what the template would look like after uploading some sample data to it?

Comment: I have added a screenshot in the question

Comment: Your question needs some work. It's unclear if your code aims to do this now or if you are asking what to **add** to your code? If your code is trying, what works about it, what doesnt? Need specifics. You sample data isn't enough to populate the whole template so looks like things are still missing

Comment: My code does half the portion. It creates separate sheets for each Modelname. But I don't know to populate the data in a template fashion. so need to know how I can do it

Comment: Why not set up a template manually and just copy that in your code and insert the relevant bits.

Comment: @SJR that's where the challenge is. I don't know to proceed beyond this.

Comment: Beyond what? Once you have set up the template just copy it in your code rather than adding a new sheet. Presumably this line `Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)`? Btw the rest of your code could be made more efficient I think.

Comment: You also need to validate that the Sheet name you're using is valid.  There are characters which are not valid in a Sheet name and your code will break if it encounters them.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting out the "get sheet" into a separate function makes your code easier to follow:

```
Sub Splitdatatosheets()

    Dim c As Range, wsModel As Worksheet, wsData As Worksheet

    Set wsData = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    For Each c In wsData.Range(wsData.Range("A4"), _
                               wsData.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Cells

        Set wsModel = ModelSheet(c.Value) 'get the model sheet
        With wsModel
            .Range("B6").Value = c.Offset(0, 1).Value 'for example
            'etc etc populate the other data
        End With

    Next c
End Sub

'get a worksheet by name - create if not found
Function ModelSheet(modelName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet, model
    model = Left(modelName, 31)
    With ThisWorkbook
        On Error Resume Next
        Set ws = .Worksheets(model)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If ws Is Nothing Then
            'no matching sheet, so create it by copying a template sheet
            .Sheets("Template").Copy after:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            Set ws = .Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
            ws.Name = model
        End If
    End With
    Set ModelSheet = ws
End Function
```